# jQuery and the this object

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery is too overpowering :(

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^(\s|&nbsp;|\u00A0)+|(\s|&nbsp;|\u00A0)+$/g, "");
}
```

when I try to add the above code, I get *"this.replace is not a function"*.

I realise that jQuery references itself as `this`, so how are you meant to reference `this`?

Comment: [Seems to work to me...](http://jsfiddle.net/Zd2zH/1/)

Comment: I don't get that error. Can you show us the invocation where the error happens?

Comment: jQuery does not reserve `this` any more than any other object. Are you sure that it's that line that gives the error?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/qjypF/ I don't see any problems. Which version of jQuery? how are you calling this function?

Comment: No worries guys. Thanks for your answers but it was a bit of an inexperienced jQuery blunder. I hadnt put the semi colon at the end of the } and it was running straight in to the jQuery function.

Comment: Note that jQuery already provides a [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) function.

Comment: Javascript also has it native from ver. 1.8.1  [string.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) but it doesn't remove `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

I forgot to put the semi colon on the end of the function and it was running in to the jQuery function

```
String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^(\s|&nbsp;|\u00A0)+|(\s|&nbsp;|\u00A0)+$/g, "");
};

(function ($) {
......
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you've posted defines a "trim" method on a String.  That allows you to do this:

```
"  some random string  ".trim();
```

Sounds like you've copied and pasted the BODY of that trim function into some other jQuery function, like this:

```
$('#myfield').change(function () {
  this = this.replace(/^(\s|&nbsp;|\u00A0)+|(\s|&nbsp;|\u00A0)+$/g, "");
});
```

Try this instead:

```
$('#myfield').change(function () {
  $(this).val($(this).val().trim());
});
```

Comment: thanks elliot. Problem solved. Just a simple semi colon missing at the end of the function {};